# Role assignment in multi-site Magento instance

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I know that Magento has multi-site, multi-domain and multi-store functionalities.
In a single instance of Magento I can reach the maximum level of data separation creating multiple websites. In fact, "a website consists of one or more stores. Websites can be set up to share customer data, or not to share any data". Assuming that I have configured two websites (website-A and website-B): I want to delegate the responsibility of a website-A to  admin-A and website-B to admin-B... is it possible? Users and roles don't have any settings to associate them to a website, and when I assign a role resource to a role, it's valid for all websites. I think that this is an important feature, I saw something like that in Prestashop, but not in Magento. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but it's a Magento Enterprise Edition feature.

There is at least one third party module I've seen that offers similar features for CE: http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html